# How to tell if a particular font has a specific glyph >64k

Tags: iphone, ios

It's relatively easy to determine if a particular Unicode font contains a glyph for a code point when the code point fits into a 64 bit value.

```
if (CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, chars, glyphs, 1)) {
    // It exists
}
```

But CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters takes an array of UniChar, which is a 16 bit type.  Is there a method for determining whether a glyph is available for a character beyond this?  For example, U+1F4A9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wound up using (where codePoint is the 32 bit code point you want to test for):

```
    UniChar characters[2];
    CFIndex length = (CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter(codePoint, characters) ? 2 : 1);

    CGGlyph glyphs[2];
    if (CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, characters, glyphs, length)) {
        // It Exists
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I've tested with the same code point you mention above (U+1F4A9). I tried two different methods of creating the UniChar characters array and in both cases I get the same values: {55357, 56489}. `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` is returning false but I'm sure it should be true for system font size 30. Any ideas for what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I was mistaken in believing that the system font has glyphs for emoji. I fixed it by using the following ctFont instead. `CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"AppleColorEmoji", 0.0, NULL);`