# How to check if a character is supported by a font

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uifont, emoji

I'm working on an app with a text field. The text wrote in this field will be printed and I have an issue with some characters like emoji, chinese characters, etc... because the font do not provide these characters.

It's why I want to get all the character provided by a font (The font is downloaded so I can deal directly with the file or with an UIFont object).

I heard about `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` but I'm not sure that this function do what I want and I can't get it work.

Here is my code :

```
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
NSString *characters = @""; // emoji character
NSUInteger count = characters.length;
CGGlyph glyphs[count];
if (CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(fontRef, (const unichar*)[characters cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], glyphs, count) == false)
    NSLog(@"CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters failed.");
```

Here `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` return **false**. It's what I want because the character '' is not provided by the font used.
The problem is when I replace `NSString *characters = @""` by `NSString *characters = @"abc"`, `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` return again **false**. Obviously, my font provide a glyph for all the ASCII characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a particular font has a specific glyph >64k](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005091/how-to-tell-if-a-particular-font-has-a-specific-glyph-64k)

Comment: You tried with 'abc'. Have you tried with the single character 'a'?

Comment: Yes, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved it :

```
- (BOOL)isCharacter:(unichar)character supportedByFont:(UIFont *)aFont
{
    UniChar characters[] = { character };
    CGGlyph glyphs[1] = { };
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)aFont.fontName, aFont.pointSize, NULL);
    BOOL ret = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, characters, glyphs, 1);
    CFRelease(ctFont);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you still need to CFRelease that font before returning, even in ARC.  CF types are not affected by ARC.

Comment: Surely this all implies a bug in CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters? You shouldn't have to create the CTFont every time...