# How to set a default font if a customised font does not support non-English character in IOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I use "FontA" as a customised font for UILabel, while there are non-English characters in it.
So iOS seems to use default system font for the non-English character.

Is there any way to set a "FontB" for the non-English characters in the case that I've already set a customised font for UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way to find out if a character is supported by a font or not.

Copy/Paste from Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136073/how-to-check-if-a-character-is-supported-by-a-font) :

```c
- (BOOL)isCharacter:(unichar)character supportedByFont:(UIFont *)aFont
{
    UniChar characters[] = { character }; // e.g ÷, ®, †, ƒ, å, ç etc.
    CGGlyph glyphs[1] = { };
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)aFont.fontName, aFont.pointSize, NULL);
    BOOL ret = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, characters, glyphs, 1);
    CFRelease(ctFont);
    return ret;
}
```

Considering you're targeting iOS6+, you need to create a `NSMutableAttributedString` and set font for each character while checking it with above method.

This is how you can set font attribute for `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
    [mutAttString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName 
                         value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17] 
                         range:NSMakeRange(characterIndex, 1)];
```

Once you have the attributed string ready. Then finally,

```
     UILabel *label;
     label.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Hope this helps.