# Is there a lightweight method to check if emoji is supported in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I'm gonna implement a emoji picker supporting [Emoji List, v14.0](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), which could show only compatible emojis, but I don't know how to check if specific emoji is compatible on current iOS version. There are several ways I found:

1. Render to PNG and compare it with default PNG (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41393387/7484856), which might be CPU-intensive.
2. Ask `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` to check if current emoji could be supported (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39606543/7484856), which seems good, but it fails to check emoji consists of two or more emojis. For example, ‍ = ( U+1F62E U+200D  U+1F4A8), which is actually not supported on iOS 13, but `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` still returns `true` because it could be represented as .
3. Persist emoji list to several `.plist` files for each iOS version, which requires some effort to maintain a lot of emoji lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list (almost) all emojis in Swift for iOS 8 without using any form of lookup tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170876/how-to-list-almost-all-emojis-in-swift-for-ios-8-without-using-any-form-of-loo)

Comment: The solution you provided is equivalent to method 3, we still need to maintain several ranges. My goal is to maintain one list or range and hide unsupported emoji if needed.